# finding the range of an input in Tableau

Tags: visualization, tableau-api

I want to create a calculator in `Tableau` that finds the final cost of a system upgrade.
I describe it using an example: The system has 2 components `A` and `B`. The cost structure is not linear and is as follows:

```
A:
quantity  unit price
<10       $5
[10,20)   $4
[20, 100) $2

B
quantity  unit price
<15       $8
[15,50)   $6
[50, 100) $4
```

Now I want to make an interface, in which the operator enters the quantity of each component and gets the final price.
For example if the input is 8 units of A and 20 units of B, the final price is 40+120=160 dollars.

My question is how to create the stepwise cost function? I assume using multiple `if`s is one way, but updating it does not seem easy. Is there a better way to do so?

Comment: Try using parameter type-in boxes for the variable unit price. Use them in your calculated fields .Keep the parameter type Integer .

Comment: If the user is entering a value, that needs to be the parameter. So in your example, you would use an integer parameter for A_Quantity and B_Quantity, and then create a calculated field that computes A_Unit_Price and B_Unit_Price based on the parameter. (So the parameter should be quantity, not unit price)